# Batch point-to-point zipcode distances

Tags: php, mysql, maps, distance

I have a zipcode database with latitudes and longitudes. I am building a loadboard and every 10 minutes we receive about 300 loads with origin and destination zipcodes.From this we need to calculate the distance between the origin and destination for each load.If our loads were not this many we would use Google maps to query each one of them. Mapquest has a batch routeMatrix that would allow us to do 25 points at a time. We tried the Haversian formular but since this is a straight line calculation its usually off by many miles.

Is there a solution that we can implement which would not lead to excessive use of server resources?

Comment: Are the points random or is there is limited set of points? If the number of points is reasonably limited, you can query Google Maps and store the results in a database for re-use.

Comment: The points are excessively random dotted across the USA.

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively get more with google directions when you can interleave your query and use up all the waypoints a single direction can hold. A direction can hold 24 waypoints hence it's 600/24 = 25 queries and 24*6*25 = 3600 queries per day. I guess it's something similar to the mapquest batch route matrix. Additionally you can save the result in a database.

Comment: They are Zipcode pairs (300 of them), eg {45122,98079},{76023,51231} They are all independent of each other, so in this case I need the distance between the paired zipcodes preferably through a batched request

Comment: And what is your problem? Put 6 pairs in a direction that can hold 24 waypoints and send it to google? Hence you can get 6 distance in 1 request? I'm missng something?

Comment: Actually the Distance Matrix would work beter except that it takes 2500 requests per day quota, way below what we have per day, Saving in a database may be a solution for request that will come later, but I bet the combination of 40 000 Zipcode distance will be massive